# How to get back the original coefficient from StandardScaler() coefficients in a Logistic regession?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I made a logistic regression and I add the StandardScaler() for normalizing the modell.

I get the coefficient, what are different from the original coefficients:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Create LogisticRegression model
log_model = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())

# Fit our data
log_model.fit(X,Y)

# Check our accuracy
print(log_model.score(X,Y))
# Check percentage of women that had affairs
print(Y.mean())

# Use zip to bring the column names and the np.transpose function to bring together the coefficients from the model
coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(X.columns, np.transpose(log_model.steps[1][1].coef_)))
```

I wanted to get back the original coefficients:
I tried The following:

```
print(log_model.steps[0][1].inverse_transform(log_model.steps[1][1].coef_, copy=None))
```

I tried the inverse transform, but it totally missleading.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe I added all the necessary imports to your code. Can you provide some dummy `X` and `Y` data along with expected and actual output to take this the rest of the way to a [MRE]? Also you say your example is without `StandardScaler`, but it's there in your code, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `inverse_transform`: that's meant to return the transformed *data* back to the original scale, not the coefficients.  For the coefficient transform, see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671638/10495893).

Comment: Hi I tried your solution `Origianal_coeff=np.divide(log_model.steps[1][1].coef_, log_model.steps[0][1].scale_)
print(Origianal_coeff)`  It seems to be good, but the result differ with some hundreds from values I get in the example like isnead: Original_coeff From the example Deviation
-0,709428099 -0,697510246 0,011917853
-0,060383496 -0,056191665 0,004191831
0,106984305 0,103776812 -0,003207493

Comment: @user15583395 By default `LogisticRegression` applies regularization, so the actual model is different with scaled and unscaled data.  You can try `penalty=None`; if still there's a difference, provide a MRE as suggested in a comment so we can try to debug.  (There might be a convergence issue with the unscaled data.)